# Difference between fontawsome 5.15.4 fontawesome.min.css and all.min.css files?

Tags: font-awesome, webfonts

What's the difference between the fontawesome.min.css and all.min.css files in version 5 of the fonts?

Answer (score 2):

fontawesome.min.css include only the common icon pack.

In the all.min.css, you got all features of fontawesome (thin, light, brand, solid, regular) as explained on their website.